# How can I concatenate two time columns in Oracle Business Intelligence?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, business-intelligence, obiee

I need to concatenate or merge two columns that have time in their rows, but when I do that I get an error that says that I can't concatenate non text columns, and I can't pass the time columns to `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` either.

I have tried things like `TO_CHAR` like this:

```
TO_CHAR("- Event Log"."Data do Evento Registado") || TO_CHAR("- Event Log"."Data do Evento Registado")
```

but I can't put the columns together. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide sample input/source date/time data and expected text output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can but you have to CAST them as chars first and the output will be pure text as well.